# Open mail client serverside with Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, server-side

Is there a way to open a mail client serverside with javascript? Im using C# and ASP.Net. Web Application. Like a mailto: type functionality. Like if i clicked the button it would open up outlook on my computer with the email address wanted already inputed. Thanks

Comment: Erm, what? Generally "Server-Side" and "JavaScript" don't mesh--JS is **Client-Side**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something of this sort:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn_email" Text="Send me an email"   OnClientClick="EmailClick" />
```

and script:

```
function EmailClick() {  
window.open("mailto:.......");  
}
```

Comment: The "mailto:" should include the target email, the subject, and the body. For example: mailto:you@company.com?subject=mysubject&body=mybody. See example in this post: https://runkiss.blogspot.com/2021/07/open-default-mail-client-from-javasctipt.html

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `Location: mailto:some@address` header. Users won't like you for doing that though; if their mail client opens unexpectedly they'll be confused/scared/annoyed.